# Count number of comments from arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array structure like this:

```
[Array[2].attributes, Array[6].attributes] contains list of objects
```

The **first array** contain blog posts with `post_id` and the **second array** contains blog comments with `comment`, `comment_id` and `post_id`

I want to count how many comments for each post and insert the count in the first array (i.e blog posts array) for each object of `post_id`

**Complete structure:**

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "created_at":"3/30/2017, 1:33:37 AM",
            "details":"aaa",
            "id":116,
            "post_id":"1490817817738",
            "title":" Technologies - Learn to code Java, Spring, Angular etc",
            "url":"-technologies---learn-to-code-java,-spring,-angular-etc",
            "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "created_at":"3/30/2017, 12:11:28 PM",
            "details":"aaa",
            "id":117,
            "post_id":"1490856088450",
            "title":"Express JS Tutorial",
            "url":"express-js-tutorial",
            "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490817936990",
            "content":"hi",
            "created_at":"2017-03-29 20:05:36",
            "id":28,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490817817738",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490856043965",
            "content":"hi",
            "created_at":"2017-03-30 06:40:43",
            "id":29,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490817817738",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490856048963",
            "content":"hwllo",
            "created_at":"2017-03-30 06:40:48",
            "id":30,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490817817738",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490856056938",
            "content":"hello",
            "created_at":"2017-03-30 06:40:56",
            "id":31,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490817817738",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490856093828",
            "content":"aaa",
            "created_at":"2017-03-30 06:41:33",
            "id":32,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490856088450",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         },
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "comment_id":"1490856096261",
            "content":"sss",
            "created_at":"2017-03-30 06:41:36",
            "id":33,
            "likes":"",
            "post_id":"1490856088450",
            "userImage":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
            "username":".k999@gmail.com"
         },
      }
   ]
]
```

I have been trying it like this but couldn't get it work:

```
var commentCount = Object.create(null);
self.postId = Object.create(null);

res[1].forEach(function(el , i) {
    console.log('el ', el);
   commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] = (commentCount[el.attributes.comment_id] || 0) +1;
});
console.log('self.commentCount ', commentCount);
```

**Update:**

```
self.data.topics = [];
var commentCount = Object.create(null);

res.forEach(function(obj){
    self.data.topics.push(obj[0].attributes);
});

res[1].forEach(function (el, i) {
    commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] = (commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log('commentCount ', commentCount);

DataMixin.data.topics = self.data.topics;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do not use the same reference of `post_id`.

```
commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] = (commentCount[el.attributes.comment_id] || 0) + 1
//                         ^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you need

```
commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] = (commentCount[el.attributes.post_id] || 0) + 1
//                         ^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^
```

You could iterate the second array and count the occurence of a given `post_id`

```js
var data = [[{ attributes: { created_at: "3/30/2017, 1:33:37 AM", details: "aaa", id: 116, post_id: 1490817817738, title: " Technologies - Learn to code Java, Spring, Angular etc", url: "-technologies---learn-to-code-java,-spring,-angular-etc", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, details: { columnName: "details", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, title: { columnName: "title", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, url: { columnName: "url", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 1000 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 45 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 45 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Post", target: "com..seeker.models.PostsCategories" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Post", target: "com..seeker.models.Comment" }], idName: "id", tableName: "post", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Post", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { created_at: "3/30/2017, 12:11:28 PM", details: "aaa", id: 117, post_id: 1490856088450, title: "Express JS Tutorial", url: "express-js-tutorial", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, details: { columnName: "details", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, title: { columnName: "title", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, url: { columnName: "url", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 1000 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 45 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 45 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Post", target: "com..seeker.models.PostsCategories" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Post", target: "com..seeker.models.Comment" }], idName: "id", tableName: "post", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Post", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }], [{ attributes: { comment_id: 1490817936990, content: "hi", created_at: "2017-03-29 20:05:36", id: 28, likes: 0, post_id: 1490817817738, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { comment_id: 1490856043965, content: "hi", created_at: "2017-03-30 06:40:43", id: 29, likes: 0, post_id: 1490817817738, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { comment_id: 1490856048963, content: "hwllo", created_at: "2017-03-30 06:40:48", id: 30, likes: 0, post_id: 1490817817738, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { comment_id: 1490856056938, content: "hello", created_at: "2017-03-30 06:40:56", id: 31, likes: 0, post_id: 1490817817738, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { comment_id: 1490856093828, content: "aaa", created_at: "2017-03-30 06:41:33", id: 32, likes: 0, post_id: 1490856088450, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }, { attributes: { comment_id: 1490856096261, content: "sss", created_at: "2017-03-30 06:41:36", id: 33, likes: 0, post_id: 1490856088450, userImage: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", username: ".k999@gmail.com" }, dirtyAttributeNames: [], frozen: false, metaModelLocal: { columnMetadata: { comment_id: { columnName: "comment_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, content: { columnName: "content", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, created_at: { columnName: "created_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, id: { columnName: "id", typeName: "MEDIUMINT", columnSize: 7 }, likes: { columnName: "likes", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, post_id: { columnName: "post_id", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, updated_at: { columnName: "updated_at", typeName: "TEXT", columnSize: 65535 }, userImage: { columnName: "userImage", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 }, username: { columnName: "username", typeName: "VARCHAR", columnSize: 200 } }, associations: [{ fkName: "comment_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.CommentRating" }, { fkName: "post_id", source: "com..seeker.models.Comment", target: "com..seeker.models.Post" }], idName: "id", tableName: "comment", dbType: "MySQL", dbName: "default", modelClass: "com..seeker.models.Comment", cached: false, versionColumn: "record_version" }, modelRegistryLocal: { callbacks: [], attributeConverters: {}, validators: [] }, cachedParents: {}, cachedChildren: {}, manageTime: true, compositeKeyPersisted: false, errors: {} }]],
        count = Object.create(null);

data[1].forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.attributes.post_id] = (count[a.attributes.post_id] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I also did the same right? Not able to find the difference

Comment: no, you have in the first part `post_id` and in the second `comment_id`, which does not match.

Comment: Can I insert into the first array using the same loop or create a new for loop?

Comment: do you mean to get the counts of `comment_id` as well?

Comment: I want to insert the result of this count `count[a.attributes.post_id] = (count[a.attributes.post_id] || 0) + 1;` into first array so that I have blog posts and comment count in one array

Comment: Updated the question. I want to insert count that matches `post_id` into the first array

Comment: oh, i understand. just assign the count where you like it.

Comment: so I have to use a new `forEach` to assign right? can't use the existing `forEach` I guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139476/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-satyadev).